# unaligned opcode in executable segment ARM assembly

Tags: assembly, arm, alignment

The goal of my program is to get an argument from the command line and store it to r0, convert it from ASCII to an integer and then back to ASCII.

I am storing it into a buffer and I need to loop through the arguments of the command line. Everything is working beautifully except that my buffer was not initialized each time the program looped to grab the next command line argument.

So my solution was to implement the procedure `resetbuffer` that resets the buffer to all 0s. Now the assembler is giving me the error: unaligned opcode in the executable segment.

I tried to insert .align 2 and .align 4 all over my program, and it still gives me the same error... tried to modify the position of the procedure call from the beginning of the loop to the end of the loop still the same problem. Any suggestions?

This is my code:

```
.text       
.global _start      
.equ exit, 1    
.equ write, 4   
.equ stdout, 1

_start:
    ldr r5, [sp]        @argc value
    ldr r6, =1
    mov r8, #8          @argv address

0:  
    ldr r4, [sp, r8]   
    add r8, r8, #4   
    ldr r0, = 1    
    mov r1,r4
    bl println       
    mov r0, r4
    bl atoi
    ldr r1, =buffer 
    bl itoa
    ldr r0, = 1
    ldr r1, =buffer
    bl print2ln
    add r6, r6, #1 
    cmp r5,r6
    ldr r1, =buffer
    bl resetbuffer
    bne 0b
    mov r0, #0      @ success exit code
    mov r7, #exit
    svc 0           @ return to os

atoi:
    push {r4, lr}
    ldr r2, =0
    ldr r3, =0
0:  
    ldrb r1, [r0], #1
    cmp r1, #'-
    beq 2f
    cmp r1, #'0
    blo 1f
    cmp r1, #'9
    bhi 1f
    sub r1,r1,#'0
    ldr r3, =0
    mov r3,r2,lsl#3
    add r2,r2,r2
    add r2,r2,r3
    add r2,r2,r1
    bal 0b

1:  cmp r4, #1
    rsbeq r2, r2, #0
    mov r0, r2
    pop {r4, pc}

2:  
    ldr r4, =1
    bal 0b
    
itoa: 
    push {r4, r5, lr}
    mov r4, r1

    
    ldr r5, =0
    push {r5}
    cmp r0,#0
    bge 4f

    0:  ldr r5, =45
    strb r5, [r4] , #1
    rsb r0, r0, #0

4:  b qr10

3:  add r1, r1, #'0
    push {r1}
    cmp r0, #0
    bne 4b

1:  pop {r5}
    cmp r5, #0
    beq 2f
    strb r5, [r4] , #1
    bal 1b

2:  ldr r0, =buffer 
    pop {r4,r5, pc}
    
    

qr10:
    mov r3, r0      @ save dividend (n)
    ldr r1, =0x1999999a @ 2^32/10
    sub r0, r0, r0, lsr #30 @ adjust for large dividends
    umull r2, r0, r1, r0    @ quotient in r0 (q)
    mov r1, r0, LSL #3  @ 8q
    add r1, r1, r0, LSL #1  @ 10q
    sub r1, r3, r1      @ remainder in r1 (r = n - 10q)
    b 3b



# determine string length
# parameters
#   r0:   address of null-terminated string
# returns
#   r0:   length of string (excluding the null byte)
# modifies r0, r1, r2
strlen:
    @ push {lr}
    mov r1, r0      @ address of string
    mov r0, #0      @ length to return
0:
    ldrb r2, [r1], #1   @ get current char and advance
    cmp r2, #0      @ are we at the end of the string?
    addne r0, #1
    bne 0b
# return
    @ pop  {pc}
    mov pc, lr      @ can do this instead of using the stack

# write a null-terminated string followed by a newline
# parameters
#   r0:  output file descriptor
#   r1:  address of string to print
# modifies r0, r1, r2
println:
    push {r4, r5, r7, lr}
# first get the string length
    mov r4, r0      @ save the fd
    mov r5, r1      @ and the string address
    mov r0, r1      @ the string address
    bl strlen       @ returns the string length in r0
    mov r2, r0      @ put length in r2 for the WRITE syscall
    mov r0, r4      @ restore the fd
    mov r1, r5      @ and the string address
    mov r7, #write
    svc 0
    mov r0, r4      @ retrieve the fd
    adr r1, CR      @ get the address of the CR string
    mov r2, #1      @ one char to write
    mov r7, #write
    svc 0
    pop {r4, r5, r7, pc}    @ restore registers and return to caller

# write a null-terminated string followed by 2 newline
# parameters
#   r0:  output file descriptor
#   r1:  address of string to print
# modifies r0, r1, r2
print2ln:
    push {r4, r5, r7, lr}
# first get the string length
    mov r4, r0      @ save the fd
    mov r5, r1      @ and the string address
    mov r0, r1      @ the string address
    bl strlen       @ returns the string length in r0
    mov r2, r0      @ put length in r2 for the WRITE syscall
    mov r0, r4      @ restore the fd
    mov r1, r5      @ and the string address
    mov r7, #write
    svc 0
    mov r0, r4      @ retrieve the fd
    adr r1, CR      @ get the address of the CR string
    mov r2, #1      @ one char to write
    mov r7, #write
    svc 0
    mov r0, r4      @ retrieve the fd
    adr r1, CR      @ get the address of the CR string
    mov r2, #1      @ one char to write
    mov r7, #write
    svc 0
    pop {r4, r5, r7, pc}    @ restore registers and return to caller

    CR: .byte '\n

resetbuffer:
    push {lr}
0:
    ldrb r0,[r1]
    cmp r0, #0

    beq 0f

    strb r0,[r1], #1
    b 0b
0:
    pop {pc}



.data
    buffer:  .space 32
```

Comment: _"I tried to insert .align 2 and . align 4 all over my program"_. Could you be more specific? Where _exactly_ did you insert them? The declaration of `CR` certainly looks like it could misalign `resetbuffer`.

Comment: If I try assembling this I get `test.s:28: Error: misaligned branch destination`. Line 28 is `bl resetbuffer`; what's right before that?

Comment: where do you guys propose i put the .align 4?

Comment: Why don't you just move `CR` down to the end, before `.data`? Otherwise the `.align` should go to before `resetbuffer`.

Comment: @artlessnoise [character literals are just weird](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Chars.html#Chars).

Comment: @Notlikethat  Indeed that is bizzare.  I wouldn't use such features.  Anyway the OP should try *divide and conquer*.